# Jquery dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, user-interface

I am having issues creating dropdown menus using jquery and css. Here is my html

```
<nav class="topNav">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="#menu" class="menu-toggle"><img src="img/main.png" /></a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#social" class="menu-toggle"><img src="img/social.png" /></a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <div class='cssmenu' id="menu">
        <ul>
            <li class='active'>
                <a href='index.html'><span>Home</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class='has-sub'>
                <a href='#'><span>Products</span></a>
                <ul>
                    <li class='has-sub'>
                        <a href='#'><span>Product 1</span></a>
                        <ul>
                            <li>
                                <a href='#'><span>Sub Item</span></a>
                            </li>
                            <li class='last'>
                                <a href='#'><span>Sub Item</span></a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class='has-sub'>
                        <a href='#'><span>Product 2</span></a>
                        <ul>
                            <li>
                                <a href='#'><span>Sub Item</span></a>
                            </li>
                            <li class='last'>
                                <a href='#'><span>Sub Item</span></a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href='#'><span>About</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class='last'>
                <a href='#'><span>Contact</span></a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class='cssmenu' id="social">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href='http://www.facebook.com'><img src="img/facebook.png" /></a>
                <a href='#'><img src="img/linked.png" /></a>
                <a href='#'><img src="img/twitter.png" /></a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

and Here is my jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            $(".cssmenu ul").hide();
            var id;
            $("a.menu-toggle").mouseenter(function(){
                id=$(this).attr("href");
                list=$($(this).attr("href")).children().first();
                list.stop(true,false).slideDown("fast");
            });
             $("a.menu-toggle").mouseleave(function(){
                     list=$(id).children().first();
                     list.stop(true,false).slideUp("fast");
             });
        });
```

Here is a video of my navbar

```
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0sCu8aj8zu2SnBuSl9BRmQ1SEE/edit?usp=sharing
```

The moment i try to move into the dropdown it slides up.If i remove the mouseleave event for the anchor tags then i can move into the drop down menus but they start stacking up.

Any help with this will be highly appreciated thank you.

Comment: Please Give me css....

Comment: see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/T8RE7/2/

Comment: I'll update it as an answer

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.cssmenu ul').hide();
    $('a.menu-toggle').hover(function () {
        var $target = $($(this).attr('href')).children('ul');
        console.log($target.get())
        clearTimeout($target.data('hoverTimer'));
        $target.stop(true, true).slideDown(500);
    }, function () {
        var $target = $($(this).attr('href')).children('ul');
        var timer = setTimeout(function () {
            $target.stop(true, true).slideUp();
        }, 200);
        $target.data('hoverTimer', timer);
    });

    $('.cssmenu > ul').hover(function () {
        clearTimeout($(this).data('hoverTimer'));
    }, function () {
        $(this).stop(true, true).slideUp();
    });

});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/T8RE7/)